# How to do intersection of two lists based on a lambda/predicate?

Tags: list, kotlin

Given two classes:

```
data class Foo(val id: Int, val foo: String)
data class Bar(val id: Int, val fId: Int, val bar: String)
```

And a list of items of each:

```
val foos: List<Foo>
val bars: List<Bar>
```

I want to intersect the list of `foos` with `bars` if the `id` in Foo matches `fId` in Bar.

Right now I'm using:

```
val actual = foos.filter {
  bars.any { b -> b.fId == it.id }
}
```

Because I use this pattern often and this is basically just an intersection I thought there's a std method in Kotlin, but couldn't find any. I was hoping for:

```
val actual = foos.intersect(bars, { (f, b) -> b.fId == f.id })
```

Since I couldn't find anything I added an extension method:

```
fun<T, U> List<T>.intersect(list2: List<U>, p: (a: T, b: U) -> Boolean): List<T> = 
  this.filter { list2.any { other -> p(it, other) } }
```

Before committing a lot of occurrences to this, I wanted to double check if the thing I'm looking for has maybe a different name and I was looking for the wrong method.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that two items in separate lists with the same id will have identical values for attributes other than id?

Comment: No, they are not the same values. In addition, usually I need to intersect based on 2 or more attributes (e.g., `id` and `version`) and not just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are many `Bar`s, it might be more efficient to put their `fID`s into a set first, since `Set.contains` is more efficient than scanning a list. Perhaps something like this:

```
val idsToRetain = bars.mapTo(mutableSetOf()) { it.fId }
val filtered = foos.filter { it.id in idsToRetain }
```

Comment: The reason that I used a predicate above is that for many occurrence I actually have to check two attributes, for example: `Bar.fId == Foo.id && Bar.fVersion == Foo.version`.

Comment: Is there an idiomatic way for this as well?

Comment: @user2084865 Looking at the extension functions of [`List`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-list/#kotlin.collections.List), nothing would seem to do what you want. There's an [`intersect`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/intersect.html) function, but it doesn't take a predicate. So, I think writing your own method for this is okay. This answer is mostly trying to show a way to improve time complexity from, I think, 
 `O(n*m)` to `O(n+m)`.